# Is it a good idea to store money using "int AmountInCents", instead of using "decimal Amount" in C#?

Tags: c#, payment

What are the pros and cons of storing money in properties without floating-point like "int AmountInCents", compared to traditionally used "decimal Amount"?

Sometimes I see that one is used and other times I see another being used. What is the better approach?

Example:

*Using AmountInCents:*

```
public class Money
{
   public int AmountInCents { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

*Using decimal Amount:*

```
public class Money
{
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

P.S.: I am omitting the "Currency" field, since it's not relevant to this question

Comment: Depends on what currencies you may want to support. Mind that there are currencies that have no cents at all and others have mills as smallest used value.

Comment: Also think about the operations you are planning to perform with the values. Will integer arithmetic be ok, or do you actually need decimal anyway at every corner?

Comment: Maximum value of Integer is only 2147483647. 2 billion more. The answer is depend on your system.

Comment: Use decimal, otherwise you'll continually need to keep dividing the cents out every time, which will be painful and error prone. The integer approaches were used in oldschool systems which predated the decimal types to avoid rounding, but this is now overcome with decimal types.

Comment: If you choose to use ints, you are going to regret it, especial if you managed to get it to production. What seems like a good idea, will cause oodles more code, oodles more degrees of freedom, and oodles more ways to get it wrong

Comment: Maybe consider something like https://github.com/danielcrenna/vault/tree/master/money

Comment: Use int. It's extremely unlikely that a central bank will notify another denomination lower than a cent. You don't have to worry about support for fractions later. If you are worried about overflow, use long.

Answer (score 2):

`decimal` really comes into its own when you are performing division or calculations on numbers that have fractional values i.e. are not integers.

It's level of accuracy is far greater than that supported by `float` or `double`. Over time multiple calculations involving these value types will introduce rounding errors, such that what we think is say `0.1` is actually `0.99999`. For this reason you can't rely on using the `==` comparator when comparing `float` or `double` values infact using something like:

`bool areEqual = Math.Abs(float1-float2)< 0.0001;` is better as it introduces an allowed tolerance on accuracy.

As an illustration of rounding error:

```
    double x = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1;
    double y = 0.3;
    double z = 0.1;
    
    double resultD=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        resultD += z;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"x -> {x}");
    Console.WriteLine($"y -> {y}");
    Console.WriteLine($"resultD -> {resultD}");
    Console.WriteLine($"x == y -> {x == y}");
    Console.WriteLine($"x == resultD -> {x == resultD}");

    decimal dec1 = 0.1m + 0.1m + 0.1m;
    decimal dec2 = 0.3m;
    decimal dec3 = 0.1m;
    
    decimal resultDec=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        resultDec += dec3;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"dec1 -> {dec1}");
    Console.WriteLine($"dec2 -> {dec2}");
    Console.WriteLine($"resultDec -> {resultDec}");
    Console.WriteLine($"dec1 == dec2 -> {dec1 == dec2}");
    Console.WriteLine($"dec1 == resultDec -> {dec1 == resultDec}");
```

Gives an output of:

```
x -> 0.3
y -> 0.3
resultD -> 0.3
x == y -> False
x == resultD -> True
dec1 -> 0.3
dec2 -> 0.3
resultDec -> 0.3
dec1 == dec2 -> True
dec1 == resultDec -> True
```

Notice how the value of `x` and `y` appear to be equal but the comparison fails, this is because the values are fractionally different.

If you are never going to use fractional values i.e. avoid division, then you can quite happily stick with integer types.